# PHP DOMDocument appendChild to end of root

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, appendchild

I've got an XML formatted like so

```
<things>
  <thing>
    <name>foo</name>
    <id>1</id>
  </thing>
  <thing>
    <name>bar</name>
    <id>2</id>
  </thing>
</things>
```

And I've created a new `<thing>` element with info from a form. When I do `$dom->appendChild($newthing)`, it's appended to the end of the document, after `</things>.` Like this

```
   <things>
     <thing>
        <name>foo</name>
        <id>1</id>
      </thing>
      <thing>
        <name>bar</name>
        <id>2</id>
      </thing>
    </things>
    <thing>
       <name>bar</name>
       <id>2</id>
    </thing>
```

Obviously I want my new element to be a child of the root element, not after it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dom->documentElement->appendChild($newthing);
```

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.documentelement):

> *documentElement*
>   This is a convenience attribute that allows direct access to the child node that is the document element of the document.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement($newthing));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to achieve same thing and I have done like this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("customer.xml");
foreach($xml->children() as $customer)
{
    if($email == $customer->email)
    {
        $error = true;
        $message = "Email Already Exist";
        break;
    }
    $id = $customer->id + 1;
}

$customer = $xml->addChild('customer');
$xml_id = $customer->addChild('id',$id);
$xml_firstName = $customer->addChild('firstName',$firstname);
$xml_lastName = $customer->addChild('lastName',$lastname);
$xml_email = $customer->addChild('email',$email);
$xml_password = $customer->addChild('password',$password);
$xml_contactNumber = $customer->addChild('contactNumber',$contactNumber);
$fp = fopen('customer.xml','w');
fwrite($fp,$xml->asXML());
fclose($fp);`[![output file][1]][1]
```